# Finding expression for $([[e_r^{\ast},e_k], e_s^{\ast}], e_l).$

Tags: vector-spaces, lie-algebras, bilinear-form, quantum-groups

> Let $(\mathfrak {g}, \mathfrak {g}_+, \mathfrak {g}_-)$ be a finite dimensional Manin triple i.e. $\mathfrak g$ is a finite dimensional Lie algebra endowed with a non-degenerate invariant bilinear form $\left \langle \cdot, \cdot \right \rangle$ and $\mathfrak g_+$ and $\mathfrak g_-$ are Lie subalgebras such that $\mathfrak g = \mathfrak g_+ \oplus \mathfrak g_-$ as vector spaces with both of $\mathfrak {g}_+$ and $\mathfrak {g}_-$ being isotropic with respect to the bilinear form $\left \langle \cdot, \cdot \right \rangle$ i.e. the bilinear form is trivial when restricted to $\mathfrak {g}_+$ and $\mathfrak {g}_-.$ In fact, in this case $\mathfrak g_+$ and $\mathfrak g_-$ are maximal isotropic with respect the bilinear form $\left \langle \cdot, \cdot \right \rangle$ (such subalgebras are called Lagrangian subalgebras). Hence the non-degenerate bilinear form $\left \langle \cdot, \cdot \right \rangle$ induces a non-degenerate pairing $(\cdot, \cdot) : \mathfrak g_- \otimes \mathfrak g_+ \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ and consequently it gives rise to a vector space isomorphism $\mathfrak g_+^{\ast} \simeq \mathfrak g_{-}.$ Thus $\dim \mathfrak {g}$ is even and $\dim \mathfrak {g}_+ = \dim \mathfrak {g}_- = \frac {1} {2} \dim \mathfrak {g}.$ Now let $(e_i)_{1}^{n}$ be a basis of $\mathfrak g_+$ and $(e_i^{\ast})_{1}^{n}$ be the dual basis of $\mathfrak g_+^{\ast} \simeq \mathfrak g_-.$ Let $[e_i,e_j] = \sum\limits_{s} \alpha_{ij}^s e_s$ and $[e_i^{\ast}, e_j^{\ast}] = \sum\limits_{s} \beta_s^{ij} e_s^{\ast}.$ Then how to compute $([[e_r^{\ast}, e_k], e_s^{\ast}], e_l)$ in terms of $\alpha_{ij}^s$ and $\beta_s^{ij}\ $? In Etingof's lecture notes on quantum groups it is claimed that $$([[e_r^{\ast}, e_k], e_s^{\ast}], e_l) = \sum\limits_{t} \alpha_{ kt}^{r} \beta_l^{ts} + \sum\limits_{t} \alpha_{tl}^{s} \beta_k^{rt}.$$

But I am having hard time obtaining this equality. First of all what is $[e_r^{\ast}, e_k]\ $? Could anyone please help me in this regard?

Thanks for your time.

**Source** $:$ Lecture Notes on Quantum Groups by Pavel Etingof and Oliver Schiffmann (Lecture $4,$ Page Nos. $34 - 35$).

[image]

[image]

Comment: $[e_r^\ast, e_k]$ is the Lie bracket of $e_r^\ast$ and  $e_k$, both of which are elements of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$. But I assume your (justified) question is: How to express this in terms of the basis $(e_1, ..., e_d, e^\ast_1, ..., e^\ast_d)$, right? --- My first attempt would be to throw the Jacobi identity on the double Lie bracket and see if that expresses that bracket in a way such that "only stars are paired with stars etc.", so we can use the given relations.

Comment: @Torstrn Schoeneberf$:$ Jacobi identity is used already. See page no. $35$ of this book. May be I will share the screenshot.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg$:$ Please have a look at equation $(4.1)$ in page no. $35.$

Comment: I admit I am very confused by this. Note in the source they do not define the parentheses $(\cdot , \cdot)$ the way you define it, but actually they do not define it at all. Either way, I already don't understand the first line in that computation. The next two equalities are okay I guess, but yup, I don't see the one you ask about either.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg$:$ The first equality is coming from the invariance of the bilinear form. Although I should admit that the pairing might not be invariant even though the bilinear form is so (for the obvious reason) because there's no reason to believe that $[[e_r^{\ast}, e_s^{\ast}], e_k] \in \mathfrak {g}_-.$

Comment: No, the very first equality, where on the LHS the input of $( \cdot, \cdot)$ seems to come from $(\mathfrak g_+^\ast \otimes \mathfrak g_+^\ast) \times (\mathfrak g_+ \otimes \mathfrak g_+)$. I do not see any kind of bracket defined on that thing.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg$:$ Oh! You mean the first equality. The LHS of the first equality just means that $\delta ([e_k, e_l]) (e_r^{\ast} \otimes e_s^{\ast}).$ Now $\delta$ is obtained by dualizing the Lie bracket $[\cdot, \cdot]$ in $\mathfrak {g}_- \simeq \mathfrak {g}_+^{\ast}.$ So we have $$\delta ([e_k,e_l]) (e_r^{\ast} \otimes e_s^{\ast}) = [e_k, e_l] ([e_r^{\ast}, e_s^{\ast}]) = ([e_r^{\ast}, e_s^{\ast}], [e_k, e_l]).$$ The last equality is obtained by identifying $\mathfrak {g}_+^{\ast \ast}$ with $\mathfrak {g}_+.$

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg$:$ The identification is done in the following way. In view of the pairing $(\cdot, \cdot)$ we have already obtained $\mathfrak {g}_+^{\ast} \simeq \mathfrak {g}_-.$ So we have $\mathfrak {g}_+^{\ast \ast} \simeq \mathfrak {g}_-^{\ast}.$ But any element of $\mathfrak {g}_-^{\ast}$ is characterized by an element of $\mathfrak {g}_+.$ Namely, the elements of $\mathfrak {g}_-$ are of the form $(\cdot, v)$ for some $v \in \mathfrak {g}_+.$ So in this identification we identify $v$ with $(\cdot, v)$ which is what we need to obtain the first equality in the book.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg$:$ This is all I understood from the context. Don't know whether it has other nice explanations or not. The idea is that $\delta ([e_k, e_l])$ is completely determined by it's action on the elements of  $\mathfrak {g}_+^{\ast} \otimes \mathfrak {g}_+^{\ast} \simeq \mathfrak {g}_- \otimes \mathfrak {g}_-$ and so it's enough to obtain it's action on the basis elements $e_r^{\ast} \otimes e_s^{\ast}$ which is what the authors tried to compute. I think it helps!

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg$:$ I think I have solved the problem.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg$:$ Using those identifications and using the isotropy of the Lie subalgebras $\mathfrak {g}_+$ and $\mathfrak {g}_-$ what I get is the following $:$ $$\begin{align*} ([[e_r^{\ast}, e_k], e_s^{\ast}], e_l) & = \sum\limits_{t} \alpha_{kt}^r \beta_l^{ts} - \sum\limits_{t} \alpha_{tl}^s \beta_k^{tr} \\ &  = \sum\limits_{t} \alpha_{kt}^r \beta_l^{ts} + \sum\limits_{t} \alpha_{lt}^s \beta_{k}^{tr} \end{align*}$$ which is slightly different and the only difference occurs in the second term. Instead of $\alpha_{tl}$ I have $\alpha_{lt}.$

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg$:$ And, if we tried to preserve $\alpha_{tl}$ in the second summation the sign before the summation will alter.

Comment: Good for you, would you mind explaining more precisely how you get that? I still don't see it, my basic problem being that I have no clue what, say, $[e_r^\ast, e_k]$ is in terms of the chosen basis vectors. Anyway, if you've got it, feel free to write an answer.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg$:$ I have found a very nice way of expressing $[e_r^{\ast}, e_k]$ in terms of the chosen basis vectors. Will I write it as a comment or as an answer?

Comment: Are you convinced with the fact that $(e_i^{\ast}, e_j) = \delta_i^j\ $?

Comment: If you can answer your own question, please do it. And yes, $(e_i^\ast, e_j) =\delta_{ij}$ is clear from definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me compute $[e_r^{\ast}, e_k].$ First write $[e_r^{\ast}, e_k] = [e_r^{\ast}, e_k]_+ + [e_r^{\ast}, e_k]_-$ for $[e_r^{\ast}, e_k]_+ \in \mathfrak {g}_+$ and $[e_r^{\ast}, e_k]_- \in \mathfrak {g}_-.$ Upon identifying $\mathfrak {g}_-$ with $\mathfrak {g}_+^{\ast}$ via the pairing $(\cdot, \cdot)$ we find that $[e_r^{\ast}, e_k]_+$ is determined by the action of the basis elements of $\mathfrak {g}_+^{\ast} \simeq \mathfrak {g}_-$ on it. So we have $$\begin{align*} (e_s^{\ast}, [e_r^{\ast}, e_k]_+) & = (e_s^{\ast}, [e_r^{\ast}, e_k])\ \ (\because \mathfrak {g}_-\ \text {is isotropic}) \\ & =([e_s^{\ast}, e_r^{\ast}], e_k)\ \ (\because (\cdot, \cdot)\ \text {is invariant}) \\ & = \left (\sum\limits_{t} \beta^{sr}_{t} e_t^{\ast}, e_k \right ) \\ & = \beta_{k}^{sr} \end{align*}$$ This shows that $[e_r^{\ast}, e_k]_+ = \sum\limits_{s} \beta_k^{sr} e_s.$ Similarly $[e_r^{\ast}, e_k]_-$ can be found by it's action on the basis elements of $\mathfrak {g}_+$ and we have $$\begin{align*} ([e_r^{\ast}, e_k]_-, e_s) & = ([e_r^{\ast}, e_k], e_s)\ \ (\because \mathfrak {g}_+\ \text {is isotropic}) \\ & = (e_r^{\ast}, [e_k, e_s])\ \ (\because (\cdot, \cdot)\ \text {is invariant}) \\ & = \left (e_r^{\ast}, \sum\limits_{t} \alpha_{ks}^{t} e_{t} \right ) \\ & = \alpha_{ks}^{r} \end{align*}$$

This shows that $[e_r^{\ast}, e_k]_{-} = \sum\limits_{s} \alpha_{ks}^{r} e_s^{\ast}.$ Thus we have $$[e_r^{\ast}, e_k] = \sum\limits_{s} \beta_{k}^{sr} e_{s} + \sum\limits_{s} \alpha_{ks}^{r} e_{s}^{\ast}.$$

Comment: @Torsten Schoeneberg$:$ Please have a look at my answer.

Comment: @Torsten Schoeneberg$:$ Could you please help me understanding the converse part i.e. given a Lie bialgebra $\mathfrak {a}$ we can construct a Manin triple. I don't understand how to extend the bracket to $\mathfrak {g} = \mathfrak {a} \oplus \mathfrak {a}^{\ast}$ so that the bilinear form $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ defined by $$\left \langle x + y, x' + y' \right \rangle = y (x') + y' (x)$$ is invariant for $x,x' \in \mathfrak {a}$ and $y,y' \in \mathfrak {a}^{\ast}.$